# Option to stop downloading HLS video when is on pause (just_audio library)

Tags: flutter, dart, http-live-streaming, just-audio

I'm using the just_audio library in my Flutter app for managing multiple live streaming stations.

I aim to cease the download of incoming HLS files when the player is paused to prevent unnecessary battery consumption.

Does anyone have suggestions or insights on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share some code to better understand it?